# can not click link inside the jquery content slider

Tags: jquery

On this page - http://goo.gl/9HiUW I have a content slider. But I can't put link inside it. When I try to put link inside it, it just shows me simple text.

My html code is-

```
<div id="one" class="contentslider">
       <div class="cs_wrapper">
           <div class="cs_slider">

               <div class="cs_article">
                  <a href="http://www.templatemo.com"> How you doing today </a> 
            </div>
```

Please help. I have searched everywhere and tried everything. I couldn't understand why is this happening.

thanks in advance,
vivid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your Website,

You have an empty span with z-index 800 which is placed over your content slider. It's found right after the div with id 'banner_right'. Hence you are clicking on the span instead of your anchor, which is why, it isn't triggering.

HTML code:

```
<div id="banner_right"><span></span>

        <div class="contentslider" id="one" style="width: 535px; height: 233px;"><a class="cs_leftBtn" href="#" style="opacity: 0; display: none;"><img src="../image-files/templatemo_left_nav.png" style="padding: 0px;"></a>
           <div class="cs_wrapper">
               <div class="cs_slider">

                   <div class="cs_article" style="width: 535px; height: 233px;"><div style="background-color:#CCC; padding:15px 0 55px 0"> 
                     <a onclick="return FIX.track(this);" href="http://www.templatemo.com">  <font size="+2">How you doing today </font></a> <img alt="Seagulls" src="http://www.successrealization.com/../image-files/templatemo_image_01.jpg">
                </div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#banner_right span {
    background: url("../image-files/templatemo_banner_image_frame.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 233px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 535px;
    z-index: 800;
}
```

**Tip:** Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect your webpage

Comment: Thank you, Mysteryos. It worked and very sorry for late replying.